# Multipass rendering using framebuffers

Tags: opengl, render-to-texture, multipass

I am trying to make multipass offscreen rendering and I stuck in one question ( more like a problem ). What's should be concept of capturing multiple passes? Currently I got this:

Init:

```
Create FBO #1
Create FBO #2

Create Postprocess shader #1 (lighting)
Create Postprocess shader #2 (gamma, exposure, color control etc..)
```

Render:

```
Bind FBO #1
RenderScene();
Unbind FBO

Bind FBO #2
Bind Postprocess shader #1
BIND FBO #1 TEXTURE ( with scene )
DRAWQUAD(); // And apply lighting etc..
Unbind;

// Now simply draw quad with FBO #1 texture.
Bind Postprocess shader #2 // Apply color corrections..
DRAWQUAD(); 
Unbind;
```

As I read in some presentation, it's better to use multiple FBOs, but some people say that it's better to use single FBO and switch attachments, - it's faster, but driver may validate too much ( performance will suffer of course ).
I am using OSX10.11, OpenGL profiler indeed shows that glBindFramebuffer is x20 slower than glFramebufferTexture(Layer.., attachment). But then in this case if I use single FBO, how should I render to texture? Because now I can't do DRAWQUAD(); twice.. Example of what I think if I will be able to use Single FBO with different attachments.

Init:

```
Create FBO #1 // Only one frame buffer.

Create Postprocess shader #1 (lighting)
Create Postprocess shader #2 (gamma, exposure, color control etc..)
```

Render:

```
Bind FBO #1 
RenderScene()
```

.. What should I do on this stage? because FBO is filled by scene data and I can't just DRAWQUAD(); here.

EDIT: Is it right thing to do?

```
    // glBindFramebuffer #1
    // draw to layer 0
    // glUnbind

    // glBindFramebuffer #1
    // draw to layer 1 texture from layer 0 ( quad )
    // glUnbind

    // glBindFramebuffer #1
    // draw to layer 2 texture from layer 1 ( quad too )
    // glUnbind

    // ... and simply draw quad with layer 2 texture
```

Comment: "*Because now I can't do DRAWQUAD(); twice..*" Um, why not?

Comment: `DRAWQUAD(); Unbind;` What exactly are you unbinding here? The FBO, the texture, or the program?

Comment: How are you measuring the 20x performance difference? If you just measure the time of the call itself, that's not really meaningful, since most of what needs to happen in response will be executed asynchronously.

Comment: Oh I got it! I've made two implementations by using glDrawBuffer( <color attachment index which will be used with glFramebufferTexture2D> ) and glFramebufferTexture2D as it is.

Comment: I am using OpenGL Profiler to see GL calls and time.